# Teradata SQL exclude errors

Tags: sql, teradata

I am reposting my query again since the original question wasn't clear. I  need to exclude the ids in the meds table from the first 2 tables. I get a expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword between ')' and ')' error.

```
select distinct first_visit.pat_id, 
            first_visit.PatientMRN, 
            first_visit.PatientName, 
            cast(contact_date as  date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') as visit_date, 
            first_visit.hsp_account_id as hsp_acct
from            
(
SELECT  distinct pat.pat_id,
    pat.PAT_MRN_ID as PatientMRN,
    pat.PAT_NAME as PatientName,
    contact_date,
    cast(pat.Birth_Date as  date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') as DOB,
    cast(contact_date as date) - cast( pat.birth_date as date) year (4) AS PatAge,
   enc.enc_type_c,
   dept.specialty,
   dept.department_name,
    specName.NAME,
    prov_name,
    acct.hsp_account_id     
FROM  Patient pat
inner JOIN  HSP_ACCOUNT acct on  acct.PAT_ID = pat.PAT_ID 
inner JOIN  Pat_enc enc on  enc.PAT_ID = pat.PAT_ID 
inner join clarity_ser_dept ser  on ser.prov_id = enc.visit_prov_id
inner join clarity_ser prov on prov.prov_id = ser.prov_id 
inner join CLARITY_SER_SPEC spec on enc.visit_prov_id = spec.PROV_ID 
inner join ZC_SPECIALTY specName on specName.SPECIALTY_C = spec.SPECIALTY_C and spec.LINE=1 and specName.NAME = 'xxx'
inner join CLARITY_DEP Dept on Dept.DEPARTMENT_ID = enc.DEPARTMENT_ID  and dept.specialty = specname.name
inner join CLARITY_LOC provLoc on provLoc.LOC_ID = Dept.REV_LOC_ID
where patAge > 55
and cast(contact_date as  date format 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= '10/01/2018'
and ACCT_CLASS_HA_C  =  '1207'
and acct.CODING_STATUS_C = 4 
and acct.ACCT_BILLSTS_HA_C NOT IN (40, 60, 99) 
AND SUBSTR(CAST (acct.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR(18)),4,1) IN ('1','3')
and enc_type_c  = '101'
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
qualify row_number() over (partition by PatientMRN  order by contact_date DESC) =1) first_visit


inner join 
(select problem.pat_ID, edg.DX_ID, noted_date
from problem_list problem
inner join clarity_edg edg on problem.DX_ID = edg.DX_ID  
--where pat_id = '212000001293964'
and DX_name like any ('%Atrial FLutter%', '%Atrial Fib%')
) DX on DX.pat_id = first_visit.pat_id and DX.noted_date < first_visit.contact_date

/* exclude */
left  join 
(select distinct pat_id 
from (select pat_id from order_med ordmed
inner join RX_MED_TWO rxmed  on ordmed.medication_id = rxmed.medication_id 
inner join ZC_ADMIN_ROUTE  zc on ADMIN_ROUTE_C = zc.med_route_c 
where medication_name  like any ( '%Coumadin%',  '%Eliquis%'))) meds
on first_visit.pat_id = meds.pat_id 
where meds.pat_id is null;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Teardata requires alias for all the derived tables.
Please add some alias before `qualify row_number()`

Here is the query:

```
select distinct first_visit.pat_id, 
            first_visit.PatientMRN, 
            first_visit.PatientName, 
            cast(contact_date as  date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') as visit_date, 
            first_visit.hsp_account_id as hsp_acct
from            
(
SELECT  distinct pat.pat_id,
    pat.PAT_MRN_ID as PatientMRN,
    pat.PAT_NAME as PatientName,
    contact_date,
    cast(pat.Birth_Date as  date format 'yyyy-mm-dd') as DOB,
    cast(contact_date as date) - cast( pat.birth_date as date) year (4) AS PatAge,
   enc.enc_type_c,
   dept.specialty,
   dept.department_name,
    specName.NAME,
    prov_name,
    acct.hsp_account_id     
FROM  Patient pat
inner JOIN  HSP_ACCOUNT acct on  acct.PAT_ID = pat.PAT_ID 
inner JOIN  Pat_enc enc on  enc.PAT_ID = pat.PAT_ID 
inner join clarity_ser_dept ser  on ser.prov_id = enc.visit_prov_id
inner join clarity_ser prov on prov.prov_id = ser.prov_id 
inner join CLARITY_SER_SPEC spec on enc.visit_prov_id = spec.PROV_ID 
inner join ZC_SPECIALTY specName on specName.SPECIALTY_C = spec.SPECIALTY_C and spec.LINE=1 and specName.NAME = 'xxx'
inner join CLARITY_DEP Dept on Dept.DEPARTMENT_ID = enc.DEPARTMENT_ID  and dept.specialty = specname.name
inner join CLARITY_LOC provLoc on provLoc.LOC_ID = Dept.REV_LOC_ID
where patAge > 55
and cast(contact_date as  date format 'mm/dd/yyyy') >= '10/01/2018'
and ACCT_CLASS_HA_C  =  '1207'
and acct.CODING_STATUS_C = 4 
and acct.ACCT_BILLSTS_HA_C NOT IN (40, 60, 99) 
AND SUBSTR(CAST (acct.HSP_ACCOUNT_ID AS VARCHAR(18)),4,1) IN ('1','3')
and enc_type_c  = '101'
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) Blah
qualify row_number() over (partition by PatientMRN  order by contact_date DESC) =1) first_visit


inner join 
(select problem.pat_ID, edg.DX_ID, noted_date
from problem_list problem
inner join clarity_edg edg on problem.DX_ID = edg.DX_ID  
--where pat_id = '212000001293964'
and DX_name like any ('%Atrial FLutter%', '%Atrial Fib%')
) DX on DX.pat_id = first_visit.pat_id and DX.noted_date < first_visit.contact_date

/* exclude */
left  join 
(select distinct pat_id 
from (select pat_id from order_med ordmed
inner join RX_MED_TWO rxmed  on ordmed.medication_id = rxmed.medication_id 
inner join ZC_ADMIN_ROUTE  zc on ADMIN_ROUTE_C = zc.med_route_c 
where medication_name  like any ( '%Coumadin%',  '%Eliquis%'))) meds
on first_visit.pat_id = meds.pat_id 
where meds.pat_id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you format your query it's much easier to find the problem:

```
LEFT  JOIN 
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT pat_id 
   FROM
    ( SELECT pat_id
      FROM order_med ordmed
      INNER JOIN RX_MED_TWO rxmed  ON ordmed.medication_id = rxmed.medication_id 
      INNER JOIN ZC_ADMIN_ROUTE  zc ON ADMIN_ROUTE_C = zc.med_route_c 
      WHERE medication_name  LIKE ANY ( '%Coumadin%',  '%Eliquis%')
    ) ----- MISSING ALIAS
 ) meds
ON first_visit.pat_id = meds.pat_id 
WHERE meds.pat_id IS NULL;
```

Of course you don't need the nested Derived Table at all:

```
LEFT  JOIN 
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT pat_id 
   FROM order_med ordmed
   INNER JOIN RX_MED_TWO rxmed  ON ordmed.medication_id = rxmed.medication_id 
   INNER JOIN ZC_ADMIN_ROUTE  zc ON ADMIN_ROUTE_C = zc.med_route_c 
   WHERE medication_name  LIKE ANY ( '%Coumadin%',  '%Eliquis%')
 ) meds
ON first_visit.pat_id = meds.pat_id 
WHERE meds.pat_id IS NULL;
```

Btw, Teradata Studio will show you the bad syntax *before* submitting and SQL Assistant jumps to the position of the error when you use a .NET connection.